# IntelliJ shortcut conventions in Linux

Tags: linux, eclipse, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

As a long time Eclipse users, I am struggling to understand the IntelliJ shortcuts (in Linux now):

- Why Ctrl+N is open a class? in Eclipse: Ctrl+N is create a new class. N means new.
- Why Ctrl+Shift+N is open a file.
- in Eclipse, we use Ctrl+Shift+T (or R) for open classes of files: T for type, R for resource.

Could anyone please help elaborate the convention IntelliJ uses for the shortcuts?

Thanks.

Comment: In IntelliJ _N_ might stand for _navigate_, which is unfortunately inconsistent with most other applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It varies from s/w to s/w that what shortcuts did they provide for users. I'm also InteliJ user since long time and used eclipse too. 
You may find the most used shortcuts on:

> https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html

You can find their conventions here with description. Hope it helped.